# How to ignore certain strings from user input?

Tags: python, string, input

Beginner question:

How do I have my input code ignore certain strings of text?

> What is your name human? **I'm Fred**
>
> How old are you *I'm Fred*?

How do I ignore user input of the word "I'm"?

> How old are you I'm Fred? I'm 25
>
> Ahh, Fred, *I'm 25* isn't that old.

How do I again ignore user input when dealing with integers instead?

This is the code I have so far:

```
name = input("What is your name human? ")

while True:
        try:
                age = int(float(input("How old are you " + name + "? ")))

                if age >= 50:
                        print(str(age) + "! Wow " + name + ", you're older than most of the oldest computers!")
                else:
                        print ("Ahh, " + name + ", " + str(age) + " isn't that old.")
                break
        except ValueError:
                print("No, I asked how old you were... ")
                print("Let us try again.")
```

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Comment: And [please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627), and please make sure each question you ask is on-topic as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.replace('replace what','replace with')` in order to acheive that.
In this scenario, you can use something like:

```
name = input("What is your name human? ").replace("I'm ","").title()

while True:
    try:
        age = int(input("How old are you " + name + "? ").replace("I'm ",""))

        if age >= 50:
            print(str(age) + "! Wow " + name + ", you're older than most of the oldest computers!")
        else:
            print ("Ahh, " + name + ", " + str(age) + " isn't that old.")
        break
    except ValueError:
            print("No, I asked how old you were... ")
            print("Let us try again.")
```

Similarly, you can use for the words you think the user might probably enter, this is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the list of words that should be ignored or removed from the input, i suggest you the following solution.

```
toIgnore = ["I'm ", "my name is ", "i am ", "you can call me "]
name = input("What is your name human? ")

for word in toIgnore:
    name = name.replace(word, "")

while True:
    try:
        age = int(float(input("How old are you " + name + "? ")))

        if age >= 50:
            print(str(age) + "! Wow " + name + ", you're older than most of the oldest computers!")
        else:
            print ("Ahh, " + name + ", " + str(age) + " isn't that old.")
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("No, I asked how old you were... ")
        print("Let us try again.")
```

The output is following

[image]